# Vinca seedling turning yellow

Tags: leaves, seedlings

I’m growing vinca from seeds under aero garden lighting.  Why they had no issue germinating I noticed some of the seedlings are turning yellow.  I’m growing them in paper cups with no holes except for one that is in a ceramic pot.  The one in ceramic pot (with a hole on the bottom) is growing much faster and without turning yellow.  Would the ones in paper cups start growing better with normal green leaves if I made holes on the bottom of the cups?  Also watering frequency is as the soil gets dry?

[image]